# Entire function having simple zero at the Gaussian integers

Tags: complex-analysis

I am trying to find the entire function with only zeros of order 1 at the Gaussian integers and no other zeros. For that I did the enumeration of Gaussian integers and try to use the same way I used to find the entire function with simple zeros at $n^2$ and no other zeros. That just comes out like a mess. 
Seriously, I don't know how to get explicit function. Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Look up "Weierstrass factorization theorem".  I don't know why you say "**the** entire function ...": it is far from unique.  One solution is
$$ g(z) = z \prod_{w \ne 0} E_{3}(z/w)$$
where the product is over all nonzero Gaussian integers $w$, and $E_3(z)$ is an elementary factor
$$ E_3(z) = (1-z) \exp\left(z + \frac{z^2}{2} + \frac{z^3}{3} \right)$$

Comment: What is your w in the elementary factor? Do we have to enumerate Gaussian integers to write down in elementary factor?

Comment: $w$ is a Gaussian integer, and the infinite product is over all Gaussian integers $w$ except $0$.  You could write this using an enumeration of the Gaussian integers, if you wish.

Comment: Sounds good. Thank you.

Comment: Usually we need to take a product $\prod_{n=1}^\infty E_{p_n}(z/a_n)$ but in this case $p_n=3$ for all $n$ does the job. +1

Answer (score 3):

You may be interested in the [Weierstrass $\sigma$ function](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Weierstrass_sigma_function), where you take the lattice $\Lambda$ to be the Gaussian integers.

Answer (score 2):

The [Jacobi theta function](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Theta_function) can be used to produce such an entire function for any lattice in $\mathbb{C}$.  For a lattice $\Lambda = \mathbb{Z}+\mathbb{Z}\tau$ with $\operatorname{Im}(\tau) > 0$ the function $$ z \mapsto \vartheta(z + \frac{1+\tau}{2};\tau)$$ is entire and has simple zeroes precisely on the lattice $\Lambda$.