# Is there an analytic function defined on $\Bbb C$ except for Gaussian integers where it has poles of order 1 and residue 1?

Tags: calculus, residue-calculus, analyticity

I need a function defined for all complex variables $z$, except for at all the Gaussian integers, where it has poles of order 1 and residue 1. The function has to be complex-analytic.

Can anyone think of such a function?

Comment: Maybe the reciprocal of one of the functions for this question works http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/264407

Comment: I see. Such a function seems like a pain to integrate over a contour, though.

Comment: Protip : Titling a question "I need a function" is a great way to get people to ignore your question. If the question is as long as this one is, feel free to just use the question in the title. Good luck

Comment: Ok, thanks rschwieb

Answer (score 2):

The Mittag-Leffler theorem ensures that there exists such a function, and one can follow a proof of that theorem to construct such a function. For example,
$$
\frac1z + z^2 \sum_{(m,n)\in\Bbb Z^2\setminus(0,0)} \frac1{(m+ni)^2(z-(m+ni))}
$$
is such a function.